# How to ensure developers filter by a foreign key in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In a legacy project we had issues where if a developer would forget a project_id in the query condition, rows for all projects would be shown - instead of the single project they are meant to see. For example for "Comments":

```
 comments [id, project_id, message ]
```

If you forget to filter by project_id you would see all projects.  This is caught by tests, sometimes not, but I would rather do a prevention - the dev should see straightaway "WRONG/Empty"!

To get around this, the product manager is insisting on separate tables for comments, like this:

```
 project1_comments [id,message]
 project2_comments [id,message]
```

Here if you forgot the project/table name, if something were to still pass tests and got deployed, you would get nothing or an error.

However the difficulty is then with associated tables.  Example "Files" linked to "Comments":

```
files [ id, comment_id, path ]
    3,     1,   files/foo/bar

project1_comments
id    |   message
1     |  Hello World

project2_comments
id    |   message
1     |  Bye World
```

This then turns into a database per project, which seems overkill.

Another possibility, how to add a Behaviour on the Comments model to ensure any find/select query does include the foreign key, eg - project_id?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In a legacy project we had issues where if a developer would forget a project_id in the query condition

CakePHP generates the join conditions based upon associations you define for the tables. They are **automatic** when you use *contains* and it's unlikely a developer would make such a mistake with CakePHP.

> To get around this, the product manager is insisting on separate tables for comments, like this:

Don't do it. Seems like a really bad idea to me.

> Another possibility, how to add a Behaviour on the Comments model to ensure any find/select query does include the foreign key, eg - project_id?

The easiest solution is to just forbid all direct queries on the `Comments` table.

```
class Comments extends Table {
    public function find($type = 'all', $options = [])
    {
         throw new \Cake\Network\Exception\ForbiddenException('Comments can not be used directly');
    }
}
```

Afterwards only `Comments` read via an association will be allowed (associations always have valid join conditions), but think twice before doing this as I don't see any benefits in such a restriction.

You can't easily restrict direct queries on `Comments` to only those that contain a `product_id` in the *where* clause. The problem is that *where* clauses are an expression tree, and you'd have to traverse the tree and check all different kinds of expressions. It's a pain.

What I would do is restrict `Comments` so that `product_id` has to be passed as an option to the finder.

```
 $records = $Comments->find('all', ['product_id'=>$product_id])->all();
```

What the above does is pass `$product_id` as an option to the default `findAll` method of the table. We can than override that methods and force `product_id` as a *required* option for *all* direct comment queries.

```
public function findAll(Query $query, array $options)
{
    $product_id = Hash::get($options, 'product_id');
    if (!$product_id) {
        throw new ForbiddenException('product_id is required');
    }
    return $query->where(['product_id' => $product_id]);
}
```

I don't see an easy way to do the above via a behavior, because the *where* clause contains only expressions by the time the behavior is executed.